# Use of 'this' in the function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In below code:

```
var x = 10;

var arr = [1,2,3];

arr.forEach(function(arr){
  this.x = 100;
});
console.log(x); // prints '10'
console.log(this.x); //  prints 'undefined'

arr.forEach( elm =>{
  this.x = 200; 
});
console.log(x); // prints '10'
console.log(this.x); // prints '200'
```

Can anyone please explain why it's happening?

Thanx in advance

Comment: in what environment are you running that code? browser?

Comment: [Javascript ES6 — Arrow Functions and Lexical `this`](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4)

Comment: There's no `this` in arrow functions. So it's just `x` what is assigned. BTW your results are inaccurate it's 100, 100, 200, 200 there's no result of 10.

Comment: in most cases, `this.x === x` at the global level

Comment: @zer00ne- The outputs are from the console that I tested by creating a JS file and running the file via node. i.e. 'node test.js'.
While running the code in the browser, the output is '10,100,10,200' respectively.

Comment: While running in the browser, the output is  '10,100,10,200' respectively While using 'let' keyword and yes '100,100,200,200' with 'var' keyword.